# Does the Radar skill also work in a pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

The "explore" category of skills has Radar:

> **Radar:** Displays cops on the minimap within a certain range.
>
> <sub>...from [the Guide](http://world.needforspeed.com/guide#driverSkills)</sub>

However, this ability is pretty pointless if limited to explore mode.

Does Radar also bring over to pursuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, very much so.

Upgrading the Radar skill to higher levels increases the radar distance, so you'll be able to spot roadblocks and spike strips earlier.

It's also fun during cooldown to watch the cops zoom right past your hiding spot :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to buy it myself to get us an answer.

Yes: it also works in pursuit mode. However, the basic radar level does not cover the full extent of your minimap (it covers 100 yards, while the minimap shows an unspecified radius of at least 200 yards) and is thus not very useful for spotting roadblocks ahead of time.